# WPF: Application resources equivalent in DLL

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I have two projects in my solution. The first project is a **WPF** application, the other is a regular **DLL** project. Inside the DLL project I have some WPF user controls. I want these controls to share some resources and define them in the DLL.

I know that in a regular WPF application, you can specify application resources in App.xaml. Is there an equivalent in a DLL project?

Comment: Do you just want to share localizable string resources?

Comment: Actually, I want all my user controls to have access to some style resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't an equivalent in a dll, because the resource loading isn't part of an assembly (exe), but part of an application. In order to load resources an application must be loaded. App is the root element of an application, rather than an exe assembly. To do the equivalent for controls in a dll you can create a separate ResourceDictionary and add it to each control's XAML by merging it into the UserControl's resources using ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.

Comment: That is the conclusion I reached as well. It's a shame the Framework does not provide something like an Assembly.Resources collection, which would let you define a merged dictionary for sharing resources between controls in an assembly. Sure, you can create a new ResourceDictionary for this purpose, but then you need to explicitly manage its lifetime. If you add it using Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(...) when your control loads, you must call Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear() when your control unloads, else the resources will leak.

Comment: If this guy is right, it is best to consider another approach: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/846062/WPF-User-Controls-Do-Not-Use-Merged-Dictionaries-f

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create a resource XAML in the DLL like this (keep sure you have all WPF assemblies referenced in the DLL):

```
<!-- name of the dictionary is MyResources in MyDLL namespace -->
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyDLL.MyResources"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="./Controls/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and add this to the resources of your App class in your WPF project:

```
public App()
{
    MyDLL.MyResources externalRes = new MyDLL.MyResources();

    this.Resources.Add("MyExternalResources", externalRes);
}
```

Comment: I am kinda looking for a self loading resource within the DLL. I feel as though I am missing something basic about ResourceDictionarys. Perhaps I phrased my question wrong?